# Animate.css + Viewport Checker delay?

Tags: jquery, css, delay, animate.css

I am using a tutorial that incorporates [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and [jQuery Viewport Checker](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker) to animate elements into my page(http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/).

I am wondering how I can modify these animations so that each animation happens in succession instead of all at once. I.E. I want the first element to animate and then as that one is about to finish the next element starts to animate, etc.

Here is what I have so far which animates all the elements at once:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post">1</div>
    <div class="post2">2</div>
    <div class="post">3</div>
    <div class="post2">4</div>
    <div class="post">5</div>
    <div class="post2">6</div>
    <div class="post">7</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInUp',
            offset: 100
        });
        $('.post2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
            offset: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pepKL/)

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually don't need Viewport Checker for this at all.  See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pepKL/3/).  It's less code and does the same thing.  The only extra code I added had to do with the timing of the animations.

```
// ANIMATION SCRIPT
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var posts = $('.container').children();

    function animateCircle() {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            $(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
        } else {
            $(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInDown');
        }
        i++;
        if (i <= posts.length) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateCircle();}, 1000);
    }

    posts.addClass('hidden');
    animateCircle(posts);
});
```

But if you want to use Check Viewport, you can change the animateCircle function to this:

```
function animateCircle() {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $(posts[i]).viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInUp',
            offset: 100
        });
    } else {
        $(posts[i]).viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
            offset: 100
        });
    }
    i++;
    if (i <= posts.length) {
        startAnimation();
    }
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pepKL/4/) showing it using jquery ViewportChecker.

Comment: Wow. This answer goes way above and beyond. Thank you so much, this is precisely what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 4):

i know this is an older post. But i found this by just typing "viewportchecker" at google.

Here is a working solution to animate the elements with delay:

```
$('.info-bar').find('li').addClass('hidden');
$('.info-bar').viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'in-viewport',
    offset: 100,
    callbackFunction: function(elem) {
        var elements = elem.find('li'),
            i = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            elements.eq(i++).addClass('visible animated pulse');
            if(i==elements.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        },250);
    }
});

<ul class="info-bar">
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this (Animate.css + Viewport Checker delay) by tweaking a bit the ViewportChecker script. I've done it with version 1.7.4. There are 3 modifications:

1) Add a "delay" option with default value 0:

```
$.fn.viewportChecker = function(useroptions){
    // Define options and extend with user
    var options = {
        classToAdd: 'visible',
        classToRemove : 'invisible',
        offset: 100,
        repeat: false,
        invertBottomOffset: true,
        callbackFunction: function(elem, action){},
        scrollHorizontal: false,
        delay: 0 // HERE
    };
    ...
```

2) Add "data-delay" functionality so the delay can be specified in the html tag:

```
// Loop through all given dom elements
$elem.each(function(){
    var $obj = $(this),
        objOptions = {},
        attrOptions = {};

    //  Get any individual attribution data
    if ($obj.data('vp-add-class'))
        attrOptions.classToAdd = $obj.data('vp-add-class');
    if ($obj.data('vp-remove-class'))
        attrOptions.classToRemove = $obj.data('vp-remove-class');
    if ($obj.data('vp-offset'))
        attrOptions.offset = $obj.data('vp-offset');
    if ($obj.data('vp-repeat'))
        attrOptions.repeat = $obj.data('vp-repeat');
    if ($obj.data('vp-scrollHorizontal'))
        attrOptions.scrollHorizontal = $obj.data('vp-scrollHorizontal');
    if ($obj.data('vp-invertBottomOffset'))
        attrOptions.scrollHorizontal = $obj.data('vp-invertBottomOffset');
    if ($obj.data('vp-delay')) // HERE
        attrOptions.delay = $obj.data('vp-delay');
    ...
```

3) Wrap the statements to be executed when the element is in the viewport, with a setTimeout call:

```
// Add class if in viewport
if ((elemStart < viewportEnd) && (elemEnd > viewportStart)){
     setTimeout(function() { // HERE
          // remove class
          $obj.removeClass(objOptions.classToRemove);

          $obj.addClass(objOptions.classToAdd);

          // Do the callback function. Callback wil send the jQuery object as parameter
          objOptions.callbackFunction($obj, "add");
      }, objOptions.delay);
      ...
```

### Usage

HTML

```
<div data-vp-animate="bounceInLeft" data-vp-delay="500">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden-o {
   opacity: 0;
 }
.visible-o {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$('[data-vp-animate]').each(function() {
    var classToAdd = 'visible-o animated '+($(this).data('vp-animate') ? $(this).data('vp-animate') : 'fadeIn');

    $(this).addClass('hidden-o').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: classToAdd
   });
});
```